# Finding which values are being grouped together in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function, which takes as input a dataframe and another parameter named "ratio"

```
def grouper(df, ratio):
    if grouping > 0:
        return df.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.map(x.value_counts()) < len(df) * ratio, 'other'))
    return df
```

This function group together those values which appear less frequently.

If my Dataframe were to be something like

```
>>> df

   Country   Manager
0    Italy     Pippo
1   France     Pluto
2  Germany     Pippo
3    Italy     Pluto
4   France     Pippo
5    Spain     Pluto
6    Italy  Paperino
7   France  Topolino
8   Norway    Minnie
```

Then using the above-mentioned function I would have:

```
>>> grouper(df, 0.2)

  Country Manager
0   Italy   Pippo
1  France   Pluto
2   other   Pippo
3   Italy   Pluto
4  France   Pippo
5   other   Pluto
6   Italy   other
7  France   other
8   other   other
```

Now, I want to find a way to mark down which values have been changed. My desired output is something like this:

```
{
    "City" : ["Germany", "Spain", "Norway"],
    "Manager" : ["Paperino", "Topolino", "Minnie"]
}
```

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it in the most bloody way possible:

```
def grouper_cat(df, grouping):
    dictionaries = df.apply(
        lambda x: (
            lambda y=x.value_counts() : (
                lambda z =y[y<len(df)*grouping] : {z.name:(z).index.tolist()}
                )()
            )()
        ).values
    result = {}
    for d in dictionaries:
        result.update(d)
    return result
```

Example:

```
>>> grouper_cat(df, 0.2)

{'Country': ['Norway', 'Germany', 'Spain'],
 'Manager': ['Topolino', 'Paperino', 'Minnie']}
```

### Note:

Compared to @jezrael answer (the new, edited one), my solution is apparently faster

```
>>> timeit(lambda : grouper_cat(df, 0.2), number=2500)
6.257032366998828

>>> timeit(lambda : grouper_cat_jez(df, 0.2), number=2500)
8.312444757999401
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictioanry comprehension with filtering each column:

```
def grouper(df, ratio):
    if ratio > 0:
        d={x:df.loc[df[x].map(df[x].value_counts()) < len(df) * ratio, x].unique().tolist() 
              for x in df.columns}
        return d
    return df

df = grouper(df, 0.2)
print (df)
{'Country': ['Germany', 'Spain', 'Norway'], 'Manager': ['Paperino', 'Topolino', 'Minnie']}
```

Comment: While the use of `where()` and `stack()` makes everything  a little bit more readable, this solution take twice the time compared to mine. I wonder if this changes for big datasets

Comment: @FedericoDorato - Can you test now?

Comment: Your solution is missing one thing: the values in the dictionary should be unique, so you have to call set() and to transform them back to a list. I've added this part to your code. The timing of your solution is now better, but it's still a little bit slower. Still +1 for the readability , and thanks a lot

Comment: @FedericoDorato - So added `unique`, you are welcome ;)

Comment: Actually I didn't use unique, I should time the code again